# Error Binding An ArrayAdapter of strings to a ListVew :( Help

Tags: android

I don't know how to bind a ListView to an Array of strings I am pulling out of a resource file.  Android.

Here is the code I have so far after hours and hours of trying to figure it out.  I can't find any clear documentation that really explains to me how to do this.  Conceptually, it feels right to me, so maybe I am missing some core Android domain knowledge.

Here is the specific problem in the log:

03-23 02:38:40.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1156): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Here is the code I am using:

### Main.xml

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/menuMain"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/menuMain_item"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </TextView>
</ListView>
```

### strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App Systems</string>
    <array name="mainMenuItems">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

### main.java

```
package com.appsystems.appname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView menuMain = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menuMain);
        String[] mainMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mainMenuItems);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa;


        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.menuMain_item, mainMenuItems);

        menuMain.setAdapter(aa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a simple list using `ArrayAdapter`, you must supply it's constructor a layout containing a single `TextView`.
Remove the `TextView` inside `menuMain` and change the arrayAdapter constructor to this:

```
aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mainMenuItems);
```

Comment: Ok, I just learned android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is part of the API.  I had no idea what that meant for hours though I saw it everywhere.  So, it seems I can use the Android API provided layout or I could create a layout with a single TextView and reference that?  If so, I assume the advantage would be I could customize my own Text View?

Comment: That's also why I tried putting aTextView within the ListView.  I wish the documentation had better explained the use of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.  Wrox's "Professional Android 2 Application Development" didn't explain this at all unfortunately.  I might take the book back and get a different Android book if I can find a recommendation.

Comment: I recommend taking your android book back and staying here and in the SDK docs as well as general online android books/websites.. etc. It's all free on the net

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to use an ArrayAdapter on a ListView I believe your main class needs to extend ListActivity

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
```

I'm also new so I'm not sure.  You might try this.